# How to get the current cursor position in NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I need to get the position of the cursor in NumericUpDown to put it back the same position after triggering the focus and thousandseperator when text changed. How can I do it?

Here I can't find out `oldPosition`.

```
    void nudNofLines_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        nudNofLines.Focus();
        nudNofLines.Select(oldPosition, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that the TextBox inside the `NumericUpDown` is acessible without using reflection trickery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *.Controls* property of the NumericUpDown control to get hold of its contained controls, and from that collection get the contained TextBox.

Don't pay too much attention to me putting the line *this.oldPosition = this.upDownTextBox.SelectionStart;* in the KeyUp event, it was just a convenient place for me to access the SelectionStart property of the TextBox which you can use to get/set the cursor position

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var x = this.nudNofLines.Controls;
        upDownTextBox = x.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
    }

    private TextBox upDownTextBox;
    private int oldPosition;

    private void nudNofLines_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.oldPosition = this.upDownTextBox.SelectionStart;
    }

    private void nudNofLines_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        nudNofLines.Focus();
        nudNofLines.Select(oldPosition, 0);

        // Also try:
        this.upDownTextBox.SelectionStart = this.oldPosition;

    }
```